# Freeform pro won't send emails

Tags: solspace-freeform

Suddenly Freeform pro isn't sending emails to the admin or the visitor. It worked but now it doesn't for some reason.

The logs report that they are sending, but they aren't being received. I'm using the basic form module that comes with EE as well and we aren't having any issues receiving those emails.

Any ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

This could be a server issue. What's your hosting solution? Also, is this an intranet (internal network) or internet app? Also, what's it look like when you visit your Control Panel here:

```
Your Site -> Home -> Administration -> Email Configuration
```

And last, but definitely not least, have you visited https://www.spamhaus.org/ today?

Comment: The basic form module that comes with EE works, so I don't think it's a server issue.

Comment: Does the sending address use the same domain as your website (like using info@yourdomain.com as the sending address for a form at www.domain.com)? I've also seen it where you have to have the form entries set to "Open" for them to send dependably.

Comment: I've discovered it's the user notification that isn't working, admin is working fine. 

Staus is set to open, I even converted this to a template. THis is driving me crazy!

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I have the same problem.